# Skip rendering of an ExtJS component sub-node in React

Tags: reactjs, optimization, extjs

We are building an explication with `React` (and `Redux`), where one component (`Component_B`) is a **wrapper** around a third-party app written in `ExtJS`.

This third-party is heavy on redrawing, so we would like to minimize the times it is re-rendered by `React`.

`Component_B` has `state` and `props` that change regularly and make `Component_B` being redrawn.
When `Component_B` `props` and `state` change, we explicitly call some of the `ExtJS` functions in order to update the `Third-Party App` visual rendering.

```
        .---------------------------------------------------------------.
        | Component_A                                                   |
        |                                                               |
        |                                                               |
        |                   .------------------------------------------.|
        |                   | Component_B                              ||
        |                   |                                          ||
        |                   |    .------------------------------------.||
        |                   |    | Third-Party App (written in ExtJS) |||
        |                   |    |                                    |||
        |                   |    '------------------------------------'||
        |                   '------------------------------------------'|
        '---------------------------------------------------------------'
```

How can we avoid that `component_B` `props` and `state` change trigger a rerendering of `Third-Party App`, although this `Third-Party App` is affected by the changes in `component_B` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a function called [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in React.

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.

So just add to your Component_B this function:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Or you want the Component_B to be re-rendered but not the ExtJS app itself? In that case please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @pagep for this swift answer. I think it's close to the solution, but I would need `Component_B` to be re-rendered (The ExtJS app is just one child of it). Do you have a solution in mind for that case?

Comment: What about putting the ExtJS app into another component C and there block the re-render?

Comment: Thanks pagep, that seems the best solution